# Drawing a seat area in wpf

Tags: wpf

New to WPF I am after some advice, pointers-articles-codesnippets that can help me to write a usercontrol containing a seating area.

Lets say a cinema has 200 seats and it a square.
I need to be able to draw 200 seats.
What is the best way to draw seats? Would you draw 200 rectangles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be done best with an `ItemsControl`, and yes, I would render each seat as a `Rectangle` so you can get all the mouse and selection events (since I imagine you want users to be able to select seats). If you want less overhead, you could step down to using rectangle geometries, but for 200 seats that are not moving, the overhead of a `Rectangle` will not be bad.

First, I would create some code-behind to store information about each seat. I am not sure what seat data you want in your model, but I think at the very least you would like to see a seat number. You could add other data such as an occupied or reserved status for the seat, but for now I have kept it simple:

```
public partial class SeatingArea : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Seats { get; private set; }

    public SeatingArea()
    {
        Seats = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
            Seats.Add(i);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now for the XAML, you need to create an `ItemsControl` and set its `ItemsSource` to the seats collection. Then, using the `ItemTemplate` property, you can control how each seat will be rendered. In this case, it is simple: we will draw a single rectangle and overlay some text containing the number on top of the rectangle. Finally, we need the seats to be arranged in a square, so we set our `ItemsPanel` property to be a `WrapPanel`. This ensures that the seats will be arranged in rows. For the finishing touches, I have added a `Trigger` that will give seats a red glow when they are moused over. You can imagine many other triggers that would not be difficult to add.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWpfApplication.SeatingArea"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Background="Beige"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="SEATING CHART" FontSize="24" Margin="0,10"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Seats}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Seat" Width="25" Height="25" Stroke="Black" Fill="Green" Margin="1,2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Seat" Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Height="300" Width="550"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

With all of this, here is the resulting (super simple) seating chart:

[alt text http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/2944/seatingchartcontrol.png](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/2944/seatingchartcontrol.png)

Comment: let me just say you are a star.
Massive thank you for your time.
This will give me some thing to go on.
In the real world we could possibly have a 60000 seat stadium etc.
divided into parts. etc...
Users will be required to lasso seats etc....
Do you know of any books or article i can read on 
Thanks again

Comment: Thanks! I would recommend MacDonald's Pro WPF in C# 2008 as well as the big Petzold book for some extreme depth (Applications = Code + Markup). For a quick but good introduction I would get Adam Nathan's WPF Unleashed.